# Python, Django, SQlite and SQLAlchemy : insert datetime data

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm currently testing a new piece of code. I created a table using Django using `models.DateTimeField()`.

When I'm adding a new row with the django admin interface, the datetime field is working properly, for example : `2024-02-28 11:00:00`

I have some datetime string data stored in a csv file. I want to insert all this data from the csv file to my database.
Example of the data I have in my csv file :

```py
[
    '2024-02-28T17:40:00+00:00',
    '2024-02-29T16:30:00+00:00',
    '2024-03-01T00:30:00+00:00',
    #...
]
```

To insert the data into my database I'm using SQLAlchemy, it works for other tables, the only field where it is not working properly is the datetime one.
This is the code :

```py
#formating the date format 
date = datetime.fromisoformat(row['date'])

#inserting in the database
session.add(
    Game(
        #...
        datetime = date,
        #...
    )
)
session.commit()
```

When I browse the data added by my script, I see that the date format is not the same as that automatically done by the django interface. I have this kind of data : `2024-02-25 14:00:00.000000`

My code doesn't work because into the same database there are two different format of datetime data.

I've tried to format the datetime string but it doesn't work either.

```py
formatted_date_time = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

I reach this error : `sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (builtins.TypeError) SQLite DateTime type only accepts Python datetime and date objects as input.`